# Full manual conversion of Epoch time to Date and Time

Tags: perl, epoch

I wrote this Perl script to convert date and time from files into epoch time.

The original date format is `dd-mm-yyyy hh:MM:ss`

The reason I do this is because I have to write these values to a database and only integer values are accepted by the columns.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;

$datestring = '07-06-2019 21:13:00';

my ($dd, $mm, $yyyy, $hh, $min, $sec) = split /\W+/, $datestring;

my $epoch = timelocal($sec,$min,$hh,$dd,$mm-1,$yyyy-1900);
print("$epoch\n");
```

Which translates the date `07-06-2019 21:13:00` to `1559934780`

The issue:
The values are now presented in a front-end which is unreadable by the user, the front-end does not have scripting utilities and I can only use numerous different calculation formulas which I can use to make it readable.

Is there a completely manual method, by simply using a calculator/calculation to translate epoch time back into user readable date and time?

Comment: Why do you ask for a "_completely manual method_"?  Do you really not want to use a library?

Comment: @zdim that is the problem, the integer is only available to the frontend, the frontend does not have any scripting functionality, other than normal translations from numeric to text, calculations like addition, multiplications etc. `:(`

Comment: "_frontend does not have any scripting functionality_"  -- then I don't understand what you ask: Not for a Perl script to do that?  What tools are available then? What do you mean by "calculator/calculation"?  Is this done on a command line, or what is the "front end"?  I'm confused :)

Comment: @zdim. ok, let me make it clearer. So it has basic functions. No items available like `Time::Local;` it can only do basic things like `$time = $hour + $min;` As manual as that `:)` manual down to the bone.

Comment: So what is "**it**" (that has basic functions) -- it's not Perl at all then?  (Why do you use Perl's variables like `$hour`? Does that system use the same notation for variables?)  The way the question reads I expect that you are asking to convert things around by Perl.

Comment: It is perl. So the front-end has a very blackboxed version of perl to do basic functions, it mostly is just little formula boxes GUI interfaces that translates to perl code. but very basic perl code can be manually entered. It is old and crappy, but I have to use it. the `$hour` variable was an example of manual. Let's rather say `$sum = 1 + 2;` So I have to basically do the reverse of the above code, without modules.

Comment: Ugh.  I see.  Date-times are hard to do correctly, but you can for that one particular system.  Then go ahead, check that your epoch starts in 1970, and account for all leaps and oddities since then to convert those seconds to year+mon+day+time.   It'll be fun :)

Comment: @zdim Thanks, you can imagine my excitement in this `:p`

Comment: @zdim I was thinking of doing something like 365.25 / 86 400 and getting 1970 in there, but that still leaves me with some conversion issues. Maybe I am just tired of this bloody long day. `:)`

Comment: @Gerry That is not even close to correct. Can you at least use the [localtime](https://perldoc.pl/functions/localtime) built in function? Or perhaps the `date` Unix utility? I would demand quite a significant paycheck to reimplement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.pl/Time::Piece) can convert in both directions simply for your local time zone.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $datestring = '07-06-2019 21:13:00';
my $time = localtime->strptime($datestring, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S');
my $epoch = $time->epoch;

...

my $time = localtime($epoch);
my $datestring = $time->strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S');
```

See any standard strftime or strptime man page for the format specifiers that are usually accepted - unfortunately the ones Time::Piece accepts are not documented.

---

Without access to Time::Piece, which is core since Perl 5.10, you can use the built in [localtime](https://perldoc.pl/functions/localtime) function, it's just a little more complicated (like timelocal).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $epoch = 1559934780;
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime $epoch;
my $date_string = sprintf '%02d-%02d-%04d %02d:%02d:%02d',
  $mday, $mon+1, $year+1900, $hour, $min, $sec;
```

Comment: "_unfortunately the ones Time::Piece accepts are not documented_" -- well, it sends us to `strptime` man page.  If those are correct specs (which in my experience have been) then that is documented.

Comment: It is not exactly: Time::Piece's strptime parser is quite custom, though of course only in the extensions.

Comment: Huh.  Then that's a bug in the docs.  If it sends me to a man page for format that implies (to me as a user) that that man page describes its format precisely (or, really, that the program uses the system's facility).

Comment: Thanks. plus one for the answer, but the problem is, the frontend perl is a blackboxed version of perl, it has limited resources to perl libraries. I need to do it at an actual `1+1=2`level `:(`

Comment: @Gerry Time::Piece is core. Unless you are on a Perl older than 5.10 or an incomplete Perl installation, you have access to it.

Comment: @Grinnz to be honest, this app is as old as the mountains. I did try the reverse of epoch, but the code does not compile when I try and save it. I know this is a funny one, but the app limits me, hence the manual methods needed.

Comment: @Gerry Note that you need `use Time::Piece` for both directions presented above, as it replaces the built in `localtime` with its own function.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Yes. So the script I posted is on proper perl to get the variables in from another system, the only way to convert the values back to readable form is manual. I do at least have `localtime` at disposal, but that does not solve my issue where I have to find a calculation method to do comparisons with.

Comment: @Gerry Added an example using the built-in `localtime`.

Comment: Dude, seems I can make it work using that edit! Thanks!

Comment: @Grinnz using libraries is cheating :)  see my answer

Answer (score 3):

In very early versions of DateTime.pm you will find a sub _rd2greg that I wrote as jd2greg for Rich Bowen's earlier and long defunct Project Reefknot.  That takes a number of days since the beginning of the year 1 and produces a year, month, and day.  You can take an epoch time divided by 86400 (seconds in a day) floored and add 719163 (the days up to the year 1970) to pass to it.

Here jd2greg and the corresponding greg2jd:

```
=head2 jd2greg

    ($year, $month, $day) = jd2greg( $jd );

    Convert number of days on or after Jan 1, 1 CE (Gregorian) to
    gregorian year,month,day.

=cut

sub jd2greg {
    use integer;
    my $d = shift;
    my $yadj = 0;
    my ( $c, $y, $m );

    # add 306 days to make relative to Mar 1, 0; also adjust $d to be within
    # a range (1..2**28-1) where our calculations will work with 32bit ints
    if ( $d > 2**28 - 307 ) {

        # avoid overflow if $d close to maxint
        $yadj = ( $d - 146097 + 306 ) / 146097 + 1;
        $d -= $yadj * 146097 - 306;
      } elsif ( ( $d += 306 ) <= 0 )
    {
        $yadj =
          -( -$d / 146097 + 1 );    # avoid ambiguity in C division of negatives
        $d -= $yadj * 146097;
    }

    $c =
      ( $d * 4 - 1 ) / 146097;    # calc # of centuries $d is after 29 Feb of yr 0
    $d -= $c * 146097 / 4;    #     (4 centuries = 146097 days)
    $y = ( $d * 4 - 1 ) / 1461;    # calc number of years into the century,
    $d -= $y * 1461 / 4;    #     again March-based (4 yrs =~ 146[01] days)
    $m =
      ( $d * 12 + 1093 ) / 367;    # get the month (3..14 represent March through
    $d -= ( $m * 367 - 1094 ) / 12;    #     February of following year)
    $y += $c * 100 + $yadj * 400;    # get the real year, which is off by
    ++$y, $m -= 12 if $m > 12;         #     one if month is January or February
    return ( $y, $m, $d );
}


=head2 greg2jd

    $jd = greg2jd( $year, $month, $day );

    Convert gregorian year,month,day to days on or after Jan 1, 1 CE
    (Gregorian).  Normalization is performed (e.g. month of 28 means
    April two years after given year) for month < 1 or > 12 or day < 1
    or > last day of month.

=cut

sub greg2jd {
    use integer;
    my ( $y, $m, $d ) = @_;
    my $adj;

    # make month in range 3..14 (treat Jan & Feb as months 13..14 of prev year)
    if ( $m <= 2 ) {
        $y -= ( $adj = ( 14 - $m ) / 12 );
        $m += 12 * $adj;
      } elsif ( $m > 14 )
    {
        $y += ( $adj = ( $m - 3 ) / 12 );
        $m -= 12 * $adj;
    }

    # make year positive (oh, for a use integer 'sane_div'!)
    if ( $y < 0 ) {
        $d -= 146097 * ( $adj = ( 399 - $y ) / 400 );
        $y += 400 * $adj;
    }

    # add: day of month, days of previous 0-11 month period that began w/March,
    # days of previous 0-399 year period that began w/March of a 400-multiple
    # year), days of any 400-year periods before that, and 306 days to adjust
    # from Mar 1, year 0-relative to Jan 1, year 1-relative (whew)

    $d += ( $m * 367 - 1094 ) / 12 + $y % 100 * 1461 / 4 +
      ( $y / 100 * 36524 + $y / 400 ) - 306;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is as manual as it gets. Let me test this on my system `:)`

Comment: This doesn't account for your local time zone, and is ridiculously complicated and impossible to audit. Just use localtime.

Comment: @Grinnz it is nevertheless what the question asked for, or at least the date part of that.  I had missed that they were using timelocal(), though; that makes things tougher.  Auditing is easy enough; compare a wide range of results to localtime()

Answer (score 0):

just a quick note : instead of having to hard-code so-many constants in, here's a quick utility function that can generate a few of the key constants by their actual definitions :

---

```
function _() {
    return \
        DAYS_IN_400YRS =  4 * (\
        DAYS_IN_100YRS = 25 * (\
        DAYS_IN_4_YRS  =  4 * (\
        DAYS_IN_CMMNYR =  8 * (8 * (5) + 5) + 5 \
                               ) +  1) - 1) + 1
}'
```

---

### `146097`

```
DAYS_IN_400YRS: 146097
DAYS_IN_100YRS:  36524
DAYS_IN_4_YRS:    1461
DAYS_IN_CMMNYR:    365
```

Or if you wanna make is really comprehensive  :

```
function __() {

   return \
     _SECS_IN_400YRS      =      (\ 
     _DAYS_IN_400YRS      =  4 * (\
     _DAYS_IN_100YRS      = 25 * (\
     _DAYS_IN_4_YRS       =  4 * (\
     _DAYS_IN_CMMNYR      =      (\
     _DT_LONG_MNTHS_IN_YR = 7) * (\
            _DAYS_IN_LONG_MNTH = (\
        _DAYS_IN_SHRT_MNTH     = (\
        _DAYS_IN_LEAP_FEBR     = (\
        _DAYS_IN_CMMN_FEBR     = (\
             _DT_WEEKS_IN_FEB  = 4 ) * (\
             _DT_DAYS_IN_WEEK  = 7 )) + 1 ) + 1 ) + 1 ) + (\
        _DT_STND_MNTHS_IN_YR   = 4 ) * \
             _DAYS_IN_SHRT_MNTH + \
             _DAYS_IN_CMMN_FEBR )     + 1 ) - 1 ) + 1 ) \
                   * (\
     _SECS_IN_DY = (_TM_HRS_IN_DY = 24 ) * (\
     _SECS_IN_HR = (_TM_MNS_IN_HR = 60 ) * (\
     _SECS_IN_MN =                  60 ) ) )
}
```

---

```
_DAYS_IN_400YRS:        146097
_DAYS_IN_100YRS:         36524
_DAYS_IN_4_YRS:           1461
_DAYS_IN_CMMNYR:           365
```

---

```
_DAYS_IN_LONG_MNTH:         31
_DAYS_IN_SHRT_MNTH:         30
_DAYS_IN_LEAP_FEBR:         29
_DAYS_IN_CMMN_FEBR:         28
```

---

```
_DT_DAYS_IN_WEEK:            7
_DT_WEEKS_IN_FEB:            4
_DT_STND_MNTHS_IN_YR:        4
_DT_LONG_MNTHS_IN_YR:        7
```

---

```
  _SECS_IN_400YRS: 12622780800

  _SECS_IN_DY:           86400
  _SECS_IN_HR:            3600
  _SECS_IN_MN:              60
_TM_MNS_IN_HR:              60
_TM_HRS_IN_DY:              24
```